# Dynamically creating new component does not work in svelte

Tags: javascript, components, svelte, sveltekit

So I'm trying to create a new component when a button is pressed.

Here's the place where the button is :

```html
<input type="color" id="todo-color" bind:value={todoColor} />
  <input
    type="text"
    id="todo-content"
    placeholder="Todo"
    bind:value={todoContent}
  />
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="isImportant"
    id="is-important"
    bind:checked={todoImportance}
  />
  <button on:click={createTodo}>Create todo</button>
```

The function that is called is this one:

```js
let todoContent: string;
  let todoColor: string = "#ff0000";
  let todoImportance: any = "default";
  const createTodo = () => {
    todoImportance
      ? (todoImportance = "important")
      : (todoImportance = "default");

    console.log(todoColor, todoContent, todoImportance);

    new Task({
      target: document.querySelector('#basic-todos'),
      todoContent,
      todoColor,
      todoImportance,
    });
  };
```

The three props must be strings, which is what they are. But I always get undefined for the three props.

I don't know at all what is bad in this code, and if you have a solution or another way to do this i'll take everything :)

Comment: I ran your code and It worked properly in the console.log. If your problem comes from the Task object, can you provide this class please?

Comment: Where I put a console.log it works good but when the component is created I get this warning for all the props: ```<Task> was created without expected prop 'content'```

Comment: You are not supposed to do that. The list should be created via an `{#each}` over data describing the items.

Comment: But then how could I create a component with these special prop every time a button is clicked ? Because I can't trigger an ```{#each}``` loop every time I click the button

Comment: The `{#each}` will automatically update when the array it loops is changed. `items = [...items, { /* data here */ }]` will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props are passed as the property `props`:

```js
new Task({
  target: document.querySelector('#basic-todos'),
  props: {
    todoContent,
    todoColor,
    todoImportance,
  },
});
```

[Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api)

(Assuming that those are the correct property names.)

But as noted, this *not* how to do a to-do list in Svelte. The data should be added to a list and `{#each}` should be used to create the items declaratively.

Something along the lines of:

```js
let items = [];
// ...
const createTodo = () => {
  // [collect/prepare data]

  items = [...items, item];
};
```

```html
{#each items as { content, color, importance }}
  <Task {content} {color} {importance} />
{/each}
```

If items are added/removed in the middle the `{#each}` needs a key, [see docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each).